# clonación de base de datos

Tags: mysql

en la pregunta anterior que me fue cerrada en la captura si se ve un error

```
CREATE DATABSE espocrmclon;
```

Sin embargo no es al error al que me refería ni por el cual puse la captura, ya que después compuse ese error poniéndolo de la siguiente forma

```
 CREATE DATABASE espocrmclon;
```

A lo que me refería es a lo que esta más abajo de la captura, donde ya utilizo el comando

```
 mysqldump -u [spectraespocrm] -p[spectra] espocrm | mysql -u [spectraespocrm] -p[spectra] espocrmclon
```

En esa parte después de presionar enter no comenzó a clonar, en lugar de eso me salió

```
->
```

Y así se quedó, ¿cual es el error que cometí?

Comment: los parámetros para las opciones (`-p`, `-u`, etc.) no van entre llaves cuadradas; eso se pone en la documentación para facilitar la lectura. Lo mismo, el pipe `|` indica que es una opción o la otra.. Debería ser algo similar a `mysqldump -u spectraespocrm -p 1234567 espocrmclon`

Comment: y al final de este comando debo poner ";" o no es necesario?

Comment: En lo que indicas que usaste no se usa punto y coma, ¿por qué deberías? Revisaste la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html)? Hay varios ejemplos allí :) Hay otros sitios con muchos [ejemplos](https://simplebackups.io/blog/the-complete-mysqldump-guide-with-examples/).